# How do I initialize elements of a GridView on creation?

Tags: android, gridview, view, getview

My android is very rusty, so this is the best way I can explain this:

1. A *card* contains an image, a value, and a URL
2. I have an array of values, a parallel array of images, and of URLs (values[i] <-> images[i] <-> URLs[i])
3. Have a GridView that I want to use to display many of these cards

The problem:

- I have a class that extends BaseAdapter to create a custom view to display the three elements of the card
- Using the getView method of said adapter, I use the "i" expected by getView as a mental index of which card we are talking about.
- Unfortunately I realized that i=0 means the currently visible first card, I thought it meant the overall first card. This makes it useless as a system to keep track of the overall position of cards.
- So, the visible elements are populated correctly in the view. But, if I scroll down and then back up, some internal elements have been jumbled up. So clicking a card might now lead to the URL of a card that was initialized after it.

**What I need help with:**

A better way to index or populate each card's content that will be permanent.

I am wildly confident I am doing this in a horrendous way. I'm imagining there must be some way to say that:

*When GridView is created -> populate each card's details and fill in GridView.*

**Current Main Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_list);

    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.cardGridView);
    gv.setAdapter(new CardView(this, cardURLs, cardNames, cardPrices, cardImages));
}
```

**Current CardView Activity:**

```
public CardView(CardListActivity mainActivity, String[] cardURLs, String[] cardNames, Double[] cardPrices, int[] cardImages){
    //...
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public class Holder{
    TextView priceTV;
    ImageView cardIV;
    String cardName;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //...
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item_view, null);

    //HERE IS WHERE I SET THE PRICE AND IMAGE USING i
    holder.priceTV.setText("$" + prices[i].toString());
    holder.cardIV.setImageResource(images[i]);

    //...
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was something else.

The actual problem ended up being caused by these Dialogs I would create to verify if the user wanted to open the website.

I was creating them inside getView, all in the same variable, which meant that the last elelemnt to get initialized would be the one used in the dialog.
I fixed this by moving the dialog creation into the onClick for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should wrap your contents into objects so that each `CardContent` object contains a url, an image and a value, Then pass those into your adapter. That will be much easier on you, you only need to maintain 1 `List` of `CardContent` rather than 3 individual lists and hoping the order doesn't get messed up.

Secondly, This sounds like a case for a `Recyclerview`. You can use a `GridLayoutManager` with a `Recyclerview` instead of a `GridView` so that your views get recycled and you have less overhead. Luckily the code is largely the same.

See https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html for pretty much what you want.